# Compare two dates using Python

Tags: python

```
import time

date1 = "31/12/2015"
date2 = "01/01/2019"


newdate1 = time.strptime(date1, "%d/%m/%Y")
newdate2 = time.strptime(date2, "%d/%m/%Y")


if newdate1 > newdate2:
    print "Certificate got Expired on ",date1
else:
    print "Certificate will be expired on ",date2
```

The above code is running fine in any online python compiler but whenever I am running it on my server I am getting the Error as
"**AttributeError: class 'org.python.modules.time' has no attribute 'strptime'**

Please note that I am not allowed to use datetime module or its function because then I'll be getting new Error as "ImportError: no module named datetime"

Comment: have you tried the datetime module? it will do what you need...

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/509283/python-no-module-named-datetime/ did you do a search

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Version of python is Python 2.3

Comment: is there any way or command to include the datetime module to the library without unistalling the currently installed version of pyhton

Comment: Strange error indeed. `org.python.modules.time` is a Jython package: http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/modules/time/package-summary.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **YYYY-MM-DD** (year-month-day) format on your date strings, you can compare them lexicographically, as strings. The lexicographical order of the characters will coincide with the chronological order. You don't even need to import modules for this.

Assuming your date strings are the same length (pad with leading zeroes where necessary), and they use the same delimiters.